# Tableau How to return dimension for the highest measure (how to return the name for highest score)?

Tags: tableau-api

Let's say I have this simple data:

```
+-------+-------+---------+
| Tests | Names | Scores  |
+-------+-------+---------+
| Test1 | John  |      95 |
| Test1 | Becky |      90 |
| Test2 | John  |      80 |
| Test2 | Becky |      85 |
+-------+-------+---------+
```

I want to write a calculated field that will return the name of the student of the highest score for each Exam. I want to do this without applying a filter to the whole chart.

Answer (score 3):

The closest solution found was using a filter on the whole chart (https://community.tableau.com/message/443167#443167). With some modification, I was able to build and avoid applying the filter:

Here's the solution I came up with. It's 2 steps:

**Step #1**: Create a Calculated Field that is a Dimension to act as a filter. This filter will be true when the Student has the highest score.
Filter: `[Scores] = {FIXED [Tests] : MAX([Scores])}`

**Step #2**: Create a Calculated Field that is a Measurement to return the name of the student when the filter is true.

```
TopStudent: attr(if [Fan] then [Name] END)
```

**ATTR will get rid of the NULLs.**

*(Edit: ATTR() returns the single unique non-null value if there is one, otherwise it displays a "*" to indicate that there are multiple values. So if more than one student got the same highest score, ATTR() will display a "*". If you want to show a single student name in the case of ties, you need a tie breaking rule -- for instance, use MIN() or MAX() instead of ATTR() to pick among the winners alphabetically.)*

Now you can use this measurement to create a chart, showing the top student, without applying a filter to the whole chart.

[image: Screenshot at the end]